# What is necessary to make my old 3-wire 30-A dryer connection compliant with current code?

Tags: dryer, grounding-and-bonding

I have a 3-wire connection for the clothes dryer, and I would like to make it compliant with current code the simplest way consistent with reasonable safety. I haven't looked at the connection block but it must be that the neutral is bonded to the chassis because the chassis is grounded.

The heavy ground wire that leads to the panel is grounded to the cold water pipe supplying the clothes washer and is exposed right next to the dryer. I could connect a wire from the ground terminal of the dryer to that ground wire and not change to a 4-wire plug and cord. In the connection block of the dryer I would remove the neutral to chassis ground bond.

Code violation? Someone could later disconnect that ground and the chassis would not be grounded. I could change to a 4-wire receptacle and connect a ground wire inside the wall or outside to the nearby heavy ground wire going to the panel.

Comment: Is this in North America?  (BTW, you might want to complete some bits your profile.)

Comment: Is the box for the dryer outlet flush with the wall or mounted to the surface of the wall?

Comment: The box is flush with the wall, i.e. inset into the wall with the cover plate of the receptacle on the room side surface of the drywall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NEMA 10-30 receptacles are grandfathered, illegal for new installation but legal to leave alone if already installed. It is not safe and it has a body count.  It is legal because of lobbying by the appliance industry.

By modifying it you lose your grandfathering and make it illegal.

Your proposal solves the safety problem electrically, but mechanically it is not code legal.   I am reluctant to say it would be "safe" because generally, code is written in ash and blood, and they wouldn't outlaw a thing unless experience has shown it causes fire or fatality.

Your best bet is to retrofit a NEMA 14-30 4-pin receptacle, and connect hot-hot-neutral to those same wires on the 14-30.  Connect ground as follows:

Code (as of NEC 2014) allows you to retrofit just a ground wire, simply by running a solo ground wire.   It does not need to use the same route as the conductors.   It cannot simply go to the rod/pipe ground source that the panel uses.  It must go back to the panel, and the same panel as the conductors.

The ground path must be the required wire size its entire run.  As long as that is true, multiple circuits (out of the same panel) can share a ground wire when retrofitting grounds.

Comment: Actually, it *can* go to the grounding electrode system as per 250.130(C)(1) considering this is an existing non-grounding-type receptacle for which 250.130(C) applies...

Comment: @Tester101, that has been part of the NEC for a long time.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey not sure why I thought it was a recent addition... deleted.

Comment: Must the 'solo ground wire' go back to the panel as one wire or could I run a ground out of the NEMA 14-30 and connect it to the nearby heavy bonding wire from the panel? This wire is exposed on and clamped to the cold water pipe supplying the clothes washer.

Comment: I'd run it back to the service panel, seriously.  The panel-ground rod bonding wire cannot have splices, but the retrofit ground can, as long as it's inside a junction box.  Your house's grounding system sounds squirreley to me, bonding to the washing machine's pipe is definitely wrong.  It should only bond on the city's side of the water meter, other than that, never use water or gas pipe as ground paths.  Wire so you don't have to re-wire if someone replaces that grounding system.

Comment: In our tract development built ca 1970 in Dallas TX the water meters are out next to the street. After 36 years of living in this house I had a pair of copper coated grounding rods installed a year or so ago right by the meter and panel. Originally these houses were grounded by a heavy copper grounding wire which connected the ground bar in the panel to a cold water copper pipe in the interior of the house. In my house it was the cold water supply to the clothes washer; in other houses it was the cold water supply to the tank water heater. The branch circuits are aluminum #12 and #10.

Comment: More grounds are always better but the grounding strap near your washer seems useless.  Sounds like a good plan to decommission it as a ground strap, and re-commission it as a safety ground (EGC). But now it must follow EGC rules, so you'd need the formality of removing it from the pipe, routing it somewhere a junction box could be mounted, and splicing there.

Comment: The connection to the water pipe is a bond to the water pipes, isn't it? Originally it was both a bond to the water pipes and the grounding wire for the panel, but when I had the two grounding rods installed and connected with a continuous heavy wire to the grounding block in the panel, that changes the classification of the old wire to simply a bond to the water pipes. So if that is the case I can't connect to it to ground the dryer?

Comment: Bonding to in-house water pipes is not a thing.    It was only ever a grounding wire for the panel, and in the wrong place to boot, maybe he didn't have enough grounding wire on the truck LOL.  As long as it still goes to the pipe, it's part of the panel grounding system (installed wrong) and not the EGC.  You cannot cross-connect grounding system and EGC and be Code.   Safe, relatively yeah, but Code bans it for a reason.